# How to know which process is changing a file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, inotify, pyinotify

I'm using an automation tool to build a virtual machine. During the this automation a config file (/etc/myprogram/cofig.ini) is becoming empty.

This file's contents are required complete the automation, but I'm clueless which process is emptying the file.

I want to monitor a file and list the name of processes changed the contents of the file.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

I saw some questions in Stackoverflow but did help. I tried to use audictl inotify and watchdog . Please let me know any better way to do this. Is there a way to do this using python.

Comment: `inotify` should be able to show whether any other processes are changing the content. How did you use it?

Answer (score 3):

The `lsof` command will show what processes are using which files:

```
lsof | grep <filename>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `lsof`. this command is for find out what processes currently have the file open.
if process opening the file, writing to it, and then closing it you can use auditing.

```
/sbin/auditctl -w /etc/myprogram/cofig.ini -p war -k config.ini-file

-w watch etc/myprogram/cofig.ini
-p warx watch for write, attribute change, execute or read events
-k config.ini-file is a search key.
```

wait till the file change then use

```
/sbin/ausearch -f /etc/myprogram/cofig.ini | more
```